# What features do I want for listening, recording on external USB sound card

Tags: usb, sound-card

My internal sound card has enough noise to be annoying when listening to music, so I'm going to get an external one.  Other than number of channels, what features are good to have.  I don't need >2.1 channels.  A microphone input might be helpful for Skype, etc.  Anything else that is good to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what a colegue said:

- OS support
- Volume dial on it is handy
- Mute button too
- Reviews on Amazon, especially looking for anyone reporting noise issue